# Class name has to be before method, must be MatcherAssert.assertThat() and not just assertThat()?

Tags: java, matcher, assertion, hamcrest

I'm using hamcrest matchers for a test. Why is it that I have to write

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat(a, Is.is(b));
```

and not just this?

```
assertThat(a, is(b));
```

My program errors when I try to use the latter. I really want to be able to use the latter because I need this code to be readable for someone who doesn't really know how to code.

Comment: Read about *static imports* and more generally about *static methods*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need can be satisfied by adding

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
```

to the imports section of your file. Static import was introduced to the Java language in 1.5, and you can read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Some programming environments support automatically adding static imports for your favorite methods and classes. In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites and add the MatcherAssert class there.

Comment: So in this case, the static import wouldn't be bad practice right? I've heard a lot about why they're bad

Comment: @Emily I am not sure what you have heard, but yes. I think in cases like testing where it is likely clear to developers which testing framework you are using, the result is more succinct code without any serious risk of confusion or mistakes.